# How does Set object clear all duplicates in an array and what is regulat and multiset?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

How does `Set.prototype` clear any duplicates in this algorithm?

The function's purpose is to take an undefined amount of arguments (arrays), and return a new array of unique values from each of the arrays.

For example `uniqueNums([2, 3, 4, 51], [23, 41, 3, 4, 51, 2], [2, 3, 99])` would return an `array` `[2, 3, 4, 51, 23, 41, 51, 99]`

```
function uniqueNums(...arrays) {
  const flatArray = [].concat(...arrays);
  return [...new Set(flatArray)];
}
```

What is `regulat` and `multiset`?

Comment: What are `regulat` and `multiset` that you are talking about? They don't occur in the code you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `concat` is used to create a single-layer-deep array from all of the subordinate arrays.

Then, `new Set(flatArray)` creates a new set from `flatArray`, which is *iterable*. In essence, this creates a set and calls `add` for each entry in `flatArray`. `Set#add` doesn't add values that are already in the set, so `new Set(flatArray)` provides a set of unique values (the point of a set is unique values).

Then, `[...theSet]` uses *spread syntax* to take the `Set` (which is also iterable) and create a new, flat array of the unique entries.

E.g., that code is effectively this:

```
function uniqueNums(...arrays) {
  const flatArray = [].concat(...arrays);
  // Create the set
  const set = new Set();
  // Add the entries; calling `add` with a value that's already in the set
  // doesn't do anything
  for (const entry of flatArray) {
    set.add(entry);
  }
  // Now `set` has unique values; get an array of them
  const result = [];
  for (const entry of set) {
    result.push(entry);
  }
  // Return the array
  return result;
}
```